# C3 Chart Brush Auto Adjustment issue

Tags: angularjs, c3.js

I have built a bar chart where i display quarter data of a particular year, on load of the chart am displaying the previous 4 quarters from the current quarter that is the last tick in the x-axis, am able to achieve this using subchart where i set extent:[data.length - 4, data.length] eg: extent[2,6]. which shows 4 quarters but when the brush is at the extreme right and when brush is clicked it adjusts automatically by increasing the brush width this is causing problem for me since i feed data to the chart on various options and whenever i change the options it keeps increasing the width on click of the brush. but this is not the case when the brush is on the mid ticks of the x-axis. Is their a way to stop the auto adjustment of the brush?if yes please suggest.

fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vprasad2108/njqr2anc/8/ (This example gives you an abstract of the problem)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
json: {
  Active: [300, 200, 160, 400, 250, 250],
  Activated: [200, 130, 90, 240, 130, 220],
  Deactivated: [30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50]
},
type: 'bar'
},
bar: {
width: {
  ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
}
// or
//width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
},
legend: {
position: 'bottom'
},
zoom: {
enabled: true
},
 axis: {
x: {
  label: {
    text: 'Quarters',
    position: 'outer-center'
  },
  extent: [2, 6],
  type: 'categorized',
  tick: {
    fit: true,
    centered: true
  }
},
y: {
  max: 100,
  label: {
    text: 'No Of Customers',
    position: 'outer-middle'
  }
}
},
subchart: {
show: true
}
});
```

html